# Gzipping Merged JS and CSS Files in Magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento

My Magento based store is at www.collectorsheritage.com  . Though the html and other files are getting gzipped, however the MERGED CSS AND JS files are not getting gzipped before being sent to the browser. Since the html files are getting gzipped I guess the gzip is enabled on server and is correct for the domain. S what is the problem why the merged css and js files are not getting compressed.

Comment: Do you have access to your Apache/ NginX configuration files? Show those here. It is probably the webserver, because that is gzipping the content. You can upload a JavaScript file manually and access it with your browser to check whether the webserver is gzipping JavaScript files.